# Sitecore items are not appearing in CD databases even though they were published

Tags: workflow, sitecore8, publishing

I have a scenario where I'm moving the items from draft to published state. In the published state there are 3 steps, each of them should publish the item on the web databases of CA and CD servers. 
Even though I can see in the logs, that the item is being published on all servers, the item does no appear to be in the database. And there's no error. 
Anyone had this issues? Or any ideas what is happening?
I'm using Sitecore 8.1 initial release

Answer (score 0):

this usually happens when the parent item does not exist in the Web-Database, that means the parent item is not published. In this situations, the fastest way to solve the problem is to compare the web and master databases with 2 different web browsers side-by-side. It can be also a Language issue, that means some parent does not exist in the publishing language or they are still in the workflow.

If I was in your shoes, I would start with the last published parent and investigate it from there.